# Хранение в базе данных или вычисление значения на клиенте

Tags: база-данных

Имеется база данных.
В ней 3 таблицы: Блюда, продукты и связующая.
У каждого продукта существует энергетическая ценность.
Соответственно у блюда она будет вычисляться суммой ценностей, входящих в нее продуктов.

***Первый вариант***: хранить ценность блюда в базе
***Второй вариант***: в таблице блюд хранить только названия, а ценность вычислять на клиенте.

Продукты блюда в любом случае будут запрашиваться.

Вопрос в том, какой вариант лучше?

Comment: Если действительно _всегда_ получаете на клиента полный перечень продуктов - то считать на клиенте. Хранить и не забывать обновлять нет смысла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первую очередь это значение должно расчитываться *всегда*: либо на стороне приложения, либо на стороне БД с помощью computed columns (если БД их поддерживает). Это обеспечит консистентность данных.

Но поскольку я не люблю держать бизнес-логику на стороне БД, то оставил бы вычисление на стороне приложения, тем более что, как вы говорите, данные всегда забираются пачкой, а расчет этот очень легкий.

Это для начала. А дальше все зависит от ваших требований...

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю третий вариант:

Блюда редактируются в админке, как правило не часто.
В момент *сохранения/обновления* блюда вычислять *вес*, и сохранять его в соответствующее поле в таблице блюд.
И далее отдавать уже значение этого поля.

*...сам пользуюсь подобным подходом, если добавит + в сторону этого решения*